# Linear factorization of the complex polynomial $z^3 -(5 + i)z^2 +(2+5i)z-10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Do a linear factorization of the following complex polynomial :

$z^3 -(5 + i)z^2 +(2+5i)z-10 $

Rearranging to $ z(z(z-(5+i))+(2+5i))-10 $ doesn't help

btw: $1, 2, 3, i$ and $(2 +i)$ aren't solutions

Comment: In the age of computers this shouldn't be a problem. Try $5$.

Comment: What website did you use to find this number ??

Comment: $-i$ is a solution, however.

Comment: The megalomaniac Stephen Wolfram's [website](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E3%E2%88%92(5%2Bi)*z%5E2%2B(2%2B5i)*z%E2%88%9210)

Comment: I assume that the author does not have problems to factor polynomials with real coefficients. This is why I added an answer containing a method to detect purely real and purely imaginary solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(z + i)\cdot(z - 2i)\cdot(z - 5)$

But why is this a problem? (please see comments below)

Comment: Thanks. But how did you proceed to find this. Does one just have to guess what number it could be ??

Comment: The short way is to guess one solution. Helen, for example, gave one (5). Then you have $(z^3 -(5 + i)z^2 +(2+5i)z-10)/(z-5) = z^2 - iz + 2$ and you can solve this quadratic equation directly.

Comment: The long way is a general method for solving cubics, discovered in the 1500s by Italian mathematicians Niccolò Tartaglia and Gerolamo Cardano.

Comment: The lazy way is to use a computer (Matlab) or the Web (http://www.wolframalpha.com/) where you can use commands like factor(expression) to get the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Andreas You should at least have mentioned (like raffaele did) that the integer real solutions must divide $-10$ (as it is in the purely real case).

Answer (score 2):

Integer roots, if any, are divisors of the zero-degree term, $-10$ in this case.

Because if $ax^3+bx^2+cx=-d$ then $x(ax^2+bx+c)=-d$ which shows that if the polynomial has an integer root this must be a divisor of $d$

This gives the possibilities $\pm 1;\;\pm 2;\;\pm5;\;\pm10$

it IS actually quite boring, but often it works. Then you do the short division and get $z^3-(5+i) z^2+(2+5 i) z-10=(x-5)(z^2-i z+2)$

and then

$$z^3-(5+i) z^2+(2+5 i) z-10=(z-5) (z+i) (z-2 i)$$

Comment: (+1) for mentioning the rational root theorem, which works here despite of the non-real coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

To find possible real solutions, seperate real-part and imaginary-part. You get

$$z^3-5z^2+2z-10$$ and $$-z^2+5z$$

The imaginary part factors as $z(-z+5)$ , the real part as $(z-5)(z^2+2)$. This way, it is easy to detect the solution $z=5$

If you substitute $z$ by $ui$ and seperate real and imaginary part, you get $$5u^2-5u-10=5(u-2)(u+1)$$ and $$-u^3+u^2+2u=-(u-2)u(u+1)$$ giving the solutions $2i$ and $-i$

Answer (score 0):

This a polynomial over the ring of *Gaussian integers* $\mathbf Z[i]$, which is a P.I.D. with units $\;1,-1,i,-i$.  As a consequence, the *rational roots theorem* remains valid in this ring, so that a ‘rational root’ of this polynomial is a divisor of $10$.

It happens that $5$ is a root, and we obtain by Horner's scheme the factorisation
$$z^3-(5+i)z^2+(2+5i)z-10=(z-5)(z^2-iz+2). $$
Now the quadratic polynomial $z^2-iz+2$ has the obvious root $-i$, so, as the product of the roots is equal to  $2$, the other root is $2i$, and we have the factorisation
$$z^3-(5+i)z^2+(2+5i)z-10=(z-5)(z+i)(z-2i).$$